# Twitter authentication, session doesn't work

Tags: node.js, session, twitter, session-cookies, twitter-oauth

First here is my code :

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'app_server', 'views'));
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'azerty',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 24*60*60*1000
  }
}))

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/auth/twitter', function(req, res){
    oa.getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send(error)
        } else {

            req.session.oauth = {};
            req.session.oauth.token = oauth_token;
            console.log('oauth.token: ' + req.session.oauth.token);
            req.session.oauth.token_secret = oauth_token_secret;
            console.log('oauth.token_secret: ' + req.session.oauth.token_secret);
            res.redirect('https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token='+oauth_token)
    }
    });
});



app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', function(req, res, next){
    if(req.session.oauth) {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }else {
        console.log("Bad world");
    }
})
```

When I go to the route `/auth/twitter` everything is ok.
When I get the response from the callback in `/auth/twitter/callback`, it looks like variables I just stored in session are gone. All my sessions are `undefined`...

Does someone have an idea ? Did I do something wrong ? Is there a better way to do ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you've got yourself a race condition.

You'll probably find the twitter OAuth response is coming back before your current request has had a chance to complete, as such your session state won't be updated in time for new request. To fix, make sure you save the session before you perform the redirect e.g.

```
req.session.oauth = {
    token: oauth_token,
    token_secret: oauth_token_secret
};
req.session.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    // redirect
});
```

The `resave: false` setting will ensure the session doesn't save twice in this case.

Comment: I just tried this... I was full of hope but it didnt't work.

Comment: @AaronAbenDanan hmm seemed like the only logical explanation I could see from your code. So to narrow this down, try creating a new temp local route e.g. `app.get('/test')` and redirect to this rather than Twitter OAuth and verify that you can see the session in that scenario? Rules out an issue with your session storage / loading.

Comment: This thing is getting weird! Sessions work while I don't use the Twitter authentication... Looks like I don't get the entire response from Twitter.

Comment: @AaronAbenDanan the Twitter response is irrelevant here though, you store the state in the session and that's what you pull out in your callback. I think you'll need to debug your session store to see what's going on during the callback request.